# Categorical Variable Treating in Data Science problem while Building Model

Tags: analytics

I came across various problem whether to consider categorical variable which really have some impact on prediction.
I want to know , whether we should consider categorical variable while building model which has around 43 levels.
category[category_level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cPLb.png)

i want to build a model for binary classification problem, for that i have already tried LevelEncoder,OneHotencoder etc from scikit learn.
But nothing works out and dont know how i can consider this categorical feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use categorical variables in predictions. If you have around 43 levels as you mentioned, you may club similar levels into a single category and so on. This will be a business decision or you can see how different categories in that variable are related to output variable. This will bring down the number of levels from 43 to a less number. Then create the dummy variables on those clubbed categories.

Comment: do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be by using ANOVA (Analysis of Variance) to see how different are the various categories in that variable. If they are not significantly different, you can club them in one category. I will share an example to explain the same.